# Connecting to remote REDIS server in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, queue, predis

I have made an instagram contender that needs to be able to process video conversions(FFMPEG) on a different server because of CPU reasons.

Both of my servers are connected by the same database.

Currently i have a local redis server working so this way i can push tasks to the background using the default redis config/queue config/database.

All of it is working so far, now i want to go to the next step and set-up a bridge to pass off the intensive tasks to a dedicated server just for doing video processing tasks.

**To sum up what i want**

1.Dispatch job from **SERVER1** and send it to **SERVER2 REDIS QUEUE** to be processed

**SERVER1(default) connection (config/queue) for redis**

```
'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
        'retry_after' => 90,
        'block_for' => null,
    ],
```

**SERVER1(default) queue (config/database)**

```
'default' => [
        'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
    ],
```

## What i have attempted

**SERVER2 Connection**

```
'videoProcessingRedis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'videoRedisQueue',
        'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
        'retry_after' => 90,
        'block_for' => null,
    ],
```

**SERVER 2 Queue**

```
'videoRedisQueue' => [
        'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'https://website.ca/'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
    ],
```

**Jobs/ConvertVideoForHLS**

```
 public function __construct(video $video)
{
    $this->onConnection('videoProcessingRedis');
    $this->onQueue('videoRedisQueue');
    $this->video = $video;
}
```

With the above attempt set i do not get any errors, however i can not view the job or even see that it has been created. even using the **php artisan queue:listen** and **php artisan queue:listen videoProcessingRedis** i can not see anything, nothing in the **failed_jobs** table and nothing in my **supervisor.log** so im assuming its got something to do with it just bouncing off the host?

## Idea 1

Set **SERVER2** redis server to be public facing

1.set the bind option on the **/etc/redis/redis.conf** file

before

```
bind 127.0.0.1
```

after

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

2. after bind has been set(**allowing all access)** i would add a port restriction on **6379** with only the **SERVER1 IP** to be able to connect

[image: Port restrictions on 6379]

Comment: Does anyone have any tips about how else to go about this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

When working with multiple servers on a Redis queue you need to make sure that the APP_NAME variable of both environments have the same value. If those are different then the worker will not see the jobs.

To check if your connection is working you could run `redis-cli -h {ip-of-server-2}` from server 1.

Comment: This prevented another 5 hours of hair pulling! Many thanks!